# Can't call a function when using $routeProvider

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an index page with `<div ng-view></div>` block in it. Here using `$routeProvider` various templates are inserted.

```
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
            css: 'css/style.css'
        })
        // route for the report page
        .when('/report', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/report.html',
            controller: 'reportController',
            css:['css/results.css','css/chart.css']
        })
        // route for the admin panel
        .when('/adminpanel', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/admin.html',
            controller: 'adminController'
        })
```

In one of the templates I have a form that upon submission calls a function using Angular `ng-click="processPdf()"`.

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="download" role="dialog">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
    <h4 class="factor-title">Download Your PDF</h4>
    <div class="window-message">
        <form class="remodal-form" name="download-pdf" id="download-pdf">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="download-email" id="email" required>
            <button ng-click="processPdf()" type="submit" class="download"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-3x"></i> <span>Download PDF</span></button>
        </form>
        <button class="back-fixit" data-remodal-target="fixit"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Back</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that once I call it, it provides invalid path: instead of saying `/report/?email=zzz.com`, it makes `?email=zzz.com/report` even though the function is used on the report template. I have no clue what to do and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please show a bit more code relating to the issue.

Comment: If you want help you will need to provide  a [mcve]. Nobody can help you debug a function they can't see

Comment: @andrei100ff how you passing you email parameter ?

Comment: are you using routeParams  to pass email in route ?

Comment: @MonicaPatel I'm passing it through input form. Then when  click submit button it should call processPdf() function without any redirection. However, when I click the button it passes ?email=zzz.com/report to my path instead of /report/?email=zzz.com which is considered by $routeProvider as a good reason to redirect.

Comment: have a look this blog may be helpful for parameter passing http://blog.hfarazm.com/angularjs-routeparams/